# AS3 variable declared as a null function

Tags: actionscript-3, function, anonymous

I have encountered an AS3 function that is declared as a `null` variable, as in:

```
public var edgeWeights:Function = null;
```

I am not sure how to use this function to change `null` to another value (e.g., a number like 2 or 3).  I thought something like `cs.edgeWeights = 2` might work, but that creates a compile error, as does `cs.edgeWeights(2);`

I believe these are anonymous functions in AS3 and I did do some research on them, but could not find a resolution to this situation.

Comment: Could you post the code you have written thus far? Also why are you trying to declare a `Function` variable, initialize it to `null`, and then try to set it equal to an `int`?

Comment: A Function cannot be set to a number value. It can return a number value, but without seeing how edgeWeights is utilized in the code, not sure how anyone can help you.

Answer (score 3):

`public var edgeWeights:Function = null;`

This notation means declaring variable `edgeWeights` of type `Function`. In Actionscript `Function` is an object and can be set to `null`.

To use it you need to set this variable to some function. For example:
`edgeWeights = function(a:int,b:int):int { return a+b }` or `edgeWeights = Math.sin`.

What function you should set there depends on your particular case.

Comment: Hmm, thanks - I am still not getting the result I am looking for.  Just to add a bit of clarity, I cannot change the "public var edgeWeights:Function = null;" statement - that is given to me by the as3 class I am calling.  So the task is how to turn that 'null' into a '3' in the program I am writing.  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you don't understand how to use the class. Your perceived task is likely a step in the wrong direction ? This answer explained a concept that you need to understand if you want to use this class you speak of.

Comment: @tomish `public var edgeWeights:Function = function():Number {return 3; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the Class that declares `edgeWeights` is `Widget`:

```
protected var widget:Widget;

protected function createWidget():void {
    widget = new Widget();
    widget.edgeWeights = widgetCallback;
}

//signature would need to match what the Widget
//actually expects this callback to do
protected function widgetCallback():void {
    trace('hi from widget callback');
}
```

Note that it's probably bad practice to have a public callback variable and not provide a default implementation, so if you have access to the source code, you should probably fix that.

Comment: Hi Amy, thanks for this.  I am puzzled why this edgeWeights function was implemented the way it was in the source code.  Seems awkward.  I'd rather try to work around it instead of recompiling the source but I may end up having to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Given any function:

```
public function someFunction()
{
    ...
}
```

You can create a "pointer" with this: `this.edgeWeights = someFunction;` (yes, without `()`)

Later you just use: `this.edgeWeights();` and you'll be calling `someFunction()`.

Comment: Thanks, this appears to work - at least it no longer crashes the program: function myFunction()
   {
    
    
   }
   
   cs.edgeWeights = myFunction;